# Load powershell script to be callable at any time

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell and was trying to use the example script posted [here](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/scripting/calculate-file-hashes-powershell-139518) (the [script itself](http://pastebin.com/AUQ5nT1C)) to calculate a file hash. I can get it to work using dot notation

```
. 'E:\Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Get-FileHash.ps1' E:\testfile.bin
```

however I want to be able to use it like the author does and just type

```
Get-Filehash E:\testfile.bin
```

I have found I can do

```
function Get-FileHash {. 'E:\Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Get-FileHash.ps1'}
```

but that does not behave correctly, it prompts me for the file when I do `Get-Filehash E:\testfile.bin`

What do I need to put in my profile script to correctly load this script and `Get-Help Get-FileHash` works correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the best practice in this situation is to put the function in a *module* rather than in a *script*. As ominous as that sounds, all it means is rename the containing file from a `.ps1` extension to a `.psm1` extension and then store it under your Documents directory (`...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\<Name>\<Name>.psm1`) where `<Name>` is the base name of your file.

You then load the module with this command:

```
Import-Module Name
```

Once loaded, you can call the functions contained within the module *and* Get-Help will recognize the commands as well. Among other things, modules provide encapsulation so one file does not pollute the context space of another.
And by the way, you do not need to write cmdlets in C#; you can also write them in PowerShell itself. By way of example, take a look at my [open-source PowerShell library](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/api/powershell/) which is all written in PowerShell and includes plenty of help recognized by `Get-Help`.

There is a lot more to know to really get the full benefit of using functions and modules--I refer you to my article [Down the Rabbit Hole-A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/) on Simple-Talk.com.

Comment: Thanks, that method was the exact thing I was looking for. Do I need to put Import-Module in to my start-up script or do I only need to do it once?

Comment: It depends:-) Normally it should be in your startup (i.e. your profile) *unless* you use an IDE that remembers the modules you loaded manually, such as PowerGUI's IDE. (That's the one I use and I highly recommend it for its intellisense and debugging capabilities.)

Comment: Thanks for the [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) recommendation, I was just using the built in ISE.

Comment: @MichaelSorens what IDE do you use today? PowerGUI is effectively obsolete.

Comment: I long ago switched to the built-in PowerShell ISE -- but be sure to also check out the amazing plugin for it,  [ISE Steroids](http://www.powertheshell.com/isesteroidsmanual/) that provides a variety of powerful aids including linting, refactoring, and a variable inspector. (I have no relationship with the authors of that plugin.)

Comment: @JohnZabroski -- sorry, forgot to tag my last comment for you.

Comment: Is there a good way documented somewhere for how to NOT have all my powershell functions in one giant file?  This seems completely awful whoever thought of this as a good idea!

Comment: @JohnZabroski I am not sure where you got the idea to put **all** your PS functions in one file; that is just what you should **not** do. See my _other_ article that may help you: [Further Down the Rabbit Hole: PowerShell Modules and Encapsulation](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/.net-tools/further-down-the-rabbit-hole-powershell-modules-and-encapsulation/)

Comment: @MichaelSorens I usually read your blog and understand what you're writing, but not that post. I found WFTools approach to implementing a psm1 file to be the easiest to use. https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/.build/WFTools.psm1

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
Set-Alias Get-Filehash "E:\Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Get-FileHash.ps1"
```

Comment: The alias works but doing `Get-Help Get-Filehash` does not return the detailed help that I would get if I did `Get-Help "E:\Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Get-Filehash.ps1"` How can I get the help to behave correctly too?

Comment: I think you have to write it as a CmdLet in that case, there's plenty of examples of those online.

Comment: I searched for a while but I only saw doing C# code in to a cmdlet examples, I could not find a script to cmdlet example.

Comment: Yea I believe you have to compile it to a managed DLL.  From what I understand, `Get-Help` will instantiate the CmdLet class and call a help method on it, so I'm not sure if you can implement that functionality in a script.  Then again, I'm not a PowerShell expert and only use it on occasion.

Answer (score 4):

Put the directory in which your script resides on your [executable `PATH` (i.e. the `PATH` environment variable).](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

BTW, your function wrapper work-around doesn't work because you are not passing the argument to the script:

```
function Get-FileHash {. 'E:\Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Get-FileHash.ps1' $args}
```

or you could create an alias (as  suggested in other answers)